# Problem: Invalid usage of undeployed classloader

Tags: java, websphere, classloader

I'm working on WAS 7 app server.

I got : "Problem: Invalid usage of undeployed classloader"
and my applications deployed dont work anymore

Meanwhile i had made no changes at all to app server.
I restarted servers but no effect. 
Should I try to redeploy all applications?

Any similar experience?

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Need more context for the error.  Can you paste an exception stack trace or a a snippet from the log file?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `META-INF` directory inside the EAR file that you deployed. Does it happen to have an `ibmconfig` directory?

If so, then this directory contains what's called "Application-Scoped Resources" and it is the root of your problem. Delete it, redeploy the EAR file and it might help.